# How to merge two xml file (Web.config)?

Tags: merge, web-config, filemerge, xmldiff

I have two xml files,if i use xmlDiffPatch of microsoft,it do Delete Element,but i Dont want to delete nodes,just replace value or add nodes,How to do that?for exampel:
web1.config
is like '
    
    
         600 
         150 
         75 
         25 
    

'
and web2.config is like this:
'

```
<PartPriceInfo xmlns:ns2="http://www.aa.com">
    <ns2:Subaru model="Outback">
        <ns2:Muffler> 700 </ns2:Muffler>
        <ns2:Bumper> 150 </ns2:Bumper>
    </ns2:Subaru>
</PartPriceInfo>
```

'
i want the results like below:

```
'
<PartPriceInfo xmlns:ns2="http://www.aa.com">
    <ns2:Subaru model="Outback">
        <ns2:Muffler> 700</ns2:Muffler>
        <ns2:Bumper> 150 </ns2:Bumper>
        <ns2:Floormat> 75 </ns2:Floormat>
        <ns2:WindShieldWipers> 25 </ns2:WindShieldWipers>
    </ns2:Subaru>
</PartPriceInfo>
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found Microsoft XML Diff and Patch Tool,and my job done good.good luck every one.